# Hidden button behind div showing just a tip

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

In a website I have a list of items. Each one of those items has a picture or a name which i'm adding inside an `<article>` tag like this:

```
<article class="client-card">
    <p><img width="211" height="106" src="./img/ftm1.png" class="post-image" alt="ftm" title="ftm" /></p>
</article>
```

This is the fiddle link to a test. Probably images will not work: http://jsfiddle.net/9wQg3/

Next to each one of those pictures i want to add a button with a magnifying glass which will be a button. This  button will also have the text: 'More information about this item' but I want to make visible only the magnifying glass while the rest of the button remains hidden behind the `<article>` tag. The items are put in rows and each row has three items, and i will display six items in each page. Each row will end in a `<div class="clear"></div>` because each article is floated left. This is the code:

```
<article class="client-card">
    <p><img width="211" height="106" src="./img/ftm1.png" class="post-image" alt="ftm" title="ftm" /></p>
</article><div class="more-info"><a href="#">More information</a></div>
<article class="client-card">
    <p><img width="211" height="106" src="./img/fluid.png" class="post-image" alt="ftm" title="ftm" /></p>
</article><div class="more-info"><a href="#">More information</a></div>
<article class="client-card">
    <p><img width="211" height="106" src="./img/chemical.png" class="post-image" alt="ftm" title="ftm" /></p>
</article><div class="more-info"><a href="#">More information</a></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<article class="client-card">
    <p><img width="211" height="106" src="./img/alcmelgar.png" class="post-image" alt="ftm" title="ftm" /></p>
</article><div class="more-info"><a href="#">More information</a></div>
<article class="client-card">
    <p>COLOMBIAN PRESERVED FLOWERS</p>
</article><div class="more-info"><a href="#">More information</a></div>
<article class="client-card">
    <p><img width="211" height="106" src="./img/fit.png" class="post-image" alt="ftm" title="ftm" /></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

And this is my stylesheet:

```
div.client-list article.client-card{
    width: 288px;
    height: 130px;
    background: transparent url(images/bg-client-card.png) no-repeat scroll center;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 24px;
/*  position: relative; */
}
div.client-list article.client-card p{
    line-height: 110px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #030303;
    font: normal 14px/110px "FuturaLtBTLight", Arial;
}
div.client-list div.more-info{
    width: 290px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background: #ea1571;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -290px;
/*  display: none; */
}
```

Ok, When I use that code, I get the following result:
[image]

As you can see, the rows are looking wrong and only 4 of them show the "More information" link. I left some code that i use for testing.

I tried different alternatives of the css as well as inserting the  inside the  tag, but nothing works, can you please point me on what am i doing wrong and how to correct it? (I forgot to point that the maximum width of the containing div is 1000px).

Comment: As coded, you should use `<figure>` instead of `<article>`

Comment: can you please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example with more code to reproduce this situation?

Comment: The provided code is insufficient. This [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/cfin1.png) is what people see based on that code only. Please consider updating your question with the whole CSS.

Comment: This is the link to a test i made with the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/9wQg3/2/ probably images will not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. place the :

   ```
   <div class="more-info"><a href="#">More information</a></div>
   <a href="#" class="more-info-control">magnyfying glass</a>
   ```

   inside the article tag
2. in css modify:

   ```
   div.client-list article.client-card{
       position: relative;
   }

   div.client-list div.more-info{
       width: 290px;
       height: 24px;
       line-height: 24px;
       background: #ea1571;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       left: -1px;
       display: none;
   }
   ```

   the important is that the article.client-card is **position: relative;**
   the  div.more-info is **inside** article and is **position: absolute;**

   This way, the div.more-info has the 0,0 reference point not top left corner of the browser     window but top left corner of the closest parent relative element (in this case it is article.client-card) 
   Playing with top/left values you can position the more info div.
3. and then, with the jquery you can control when to show the "more info" div (only an example code)

   ```
   $jq("more-info-control").click(function(event) {
        $jq("div.more-info", $jq(this).parent()).show();
   });
   ```